# SQLAlchemy - query id from helper table through reference

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to build a flexible database model that will allow me to store firewall rules. My (slightly simplified by removing irrelevant parts for clarity) database schema looks like this:

[image: DB schema]

My SQLAlchemy database model (for a Flask project) looks like this:

```
class FirewallRule(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    src_ip = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=True)
    dst_ip = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=True)
    port_expression = db.relationship('PortExpression', backref='firewall_rules',
            lazy='dynamic')
    firewall_rule_protocol = db.relationship('Protocol', secondary=firewall_rule_protocol,
            lazy='dynamic', backref=db.backref('firewall_rules', lazy='dynamic'))
    def add_protocol(self, protocol_number):
        protocol = Protocol.query.filter_by(protocol_number=protocol_number).first()
        if protocol and protocol in self.firewall_rule_protocol:
            return
        if not protocol:
            return
        self.firewall_rule_protocol.append(protocol)

class PortExpression(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    direction = db.Column(db.String(3), nullable=True)
    port_expression = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    firewall_rule_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('firewall_rule.id'), nullable=False)
    firewall_rule_protocol_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('firewall_rule_protocol.id'), nullable=False)

    def add_port_expr(self, direction, expr, firewall_rule_id, firewall_rule_protocol_id):
        firewall_rule=FirewallRule.query.filter_by(id=firewall_rule_id).first()
        self.direction = direction
        self.port_expression = expr
        self.firewall_rule_id = firewall_rule_id
        self.firewall_rule_protocol_id = firewall_rule_protocol_id

class Protocol(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    protocol_name = db.Column(db.String(8), nullable=False)
    protocol_number = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

firewall_rule_protocol = db.Table('firewall_rule_protocol',
        db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True),
        db.Column('firewall_rule_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('firewall_rule.id'), nullable=False),
        db.Column('protocol_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('protocol.id'), nullable=False))
```

Now my question is how can I query for `id` of records in `firewall_rule_protocol` table that are related to `certain firewall_rule` record?

In my views.py I do the following:

```
    if form.validate_on_submit(): 
        firewall_rule = FirewallRule()
        form.populate_obj(firewall_rule)
        firewall_rule.add_protocol(form.protocol.data)
        db.session.add(firewall_rule)
        db.session.flush()
        if form.port.data:
            port = PortExpression()
            direction = None
            port.add_port_expr(None, form.port.data, firewall_rule.id, firewall_rule.firewall_rule_protocol.id)
```

Above fails with following error message:

```
port.add_port_expr(None, form.port.data, firewall_rule.id, firewall_rule.firewall_rule_protocol.id)
```

`AttributeError: 'AppenderBaseQuery' object has no attribute 'id'`

Looks like I am doing something stupid, but cannot figure out myself what is it. Thanks in advance for any help or pointers in the right direction.

Regards,
Sergiusz